# Whether SharePoint content database is encrypted

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, content-database

I have been asked by the security team of my client that whether the data in SharePoint (`here SP2013`) is encrypted or not.
If it is encrypted, what is the type of encryption used and things related to it.

If it is not encrypted, how can we do this with minimum effort ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint store the data in the content Database un-encrypted, anyone who has access to the servers can steal the data or if the backups compromised.

If your organization required the strict control then you can implement the encryption. Keep in mind, when you enable the encryption ( anyform) you have to pay for the performance.

There are couple of solutions.

1. Most Popular and easy is TDE (Transparent Data Encryption), it encrypt the files on the SQL server including ( .mdf, .ldf and temp db) but will not protect the data in the memory or communication channels.It is easy to setup and no extra cost required. Only SQL Server Enterprise edition required.
2. An other option is use 3rd party encryption

Answer (score 2):

Data are all stored in the SharePoint content DB *unencrypted*. Anyone who can access the DB can very easily read all content.
You can see options [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rycampbe/2013/10/14/securing-sharepoint-harden-sql-server-in-sharepoint-environments/), but I'm not sure they'll be completely satisfying, but the TDE approach described in it protects the DB in case the backups/disks are compromised.